# WordPress Image Compression / Plugins WebP Conversion

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried adding filters to WordPress

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});
add_filter('wp_editor_set_quality', function($arg){return 100;});
```

I have tried saving the images over 20 times from photoshop (I always save for web and optimize it but I tried without optimizing too)

I tried different plugins: Smush, EWWW, Imagify, Coverter For Media.

And I still can't fix my issue.

I have 2 sizes of images, 655x655 and 426x426. I upload 655x655 and the cropped one created by wordpress (426x426) is always bad quality.

Also when plugins convert my images from jpg to webp to use them to save some kB, they also look blurry. How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/optipic/

There you can adjust conversion quality to Webp.
Try different quality options.

Installation steps:

Step #1: Download plugin WordPress WebP
Download and install the official CDN OptiPic plugin for WordPress on your site.

Step #2: Sign up for OptiPic CDN
Register in your OptiPic CDN account and add a new site to your CDN control panel.

Step #3: Copy site ID
Copy the ID of the created website to the clipboard (Ctrl + C)

Step #3.1: Optionally, you may change the compression and conversion settings:

- Image Optimization Quality
- EXIF/IPTC meta tags optimization settings
- etc (see screenshot below)

Step #4: Paste the site ID into the plugin WordPress WebP
Go to the settings page of the previously installed plugin on your site.
Paste the copied site ID into the corresponding settings field.

Step #5: Save your settings
Save plugin settings. Clear the cache in the control panel WordPress.
Change other plugin settings if necessary

Installation video:
https://youtu.be/pznYZdRJ0X4

Detailed description of all options and installation instructions:
https://optipic.io/en/webp/wordpress/

[image]